# laravel get only the first row in duplicate data

Tags: mysql

I have a users table that contains duplicate data which doesn't have any unique identifier,
so the only solution I think is get only the first row of the duplicate data
and add a new column `main` and set the value to `1`.

note: it doesn't have `created_at` or any `date` of when it's inserted

example data I have:
the `main` will be mark as `1` if the query gets the first row of duplicate data

```
  +-------------------------------------------------+
  |  id   |  username   |       name     |   main   |
  +-------------------------------------------------+
  |  1    |    test1    |     John Doe   |     0    |
  |  2    |    test2    |     John Doe   |     0    |
  |  3    |    test3    |     John Doe   |     0    |
  |  4    |    test4    |     John Doe   |     0    |
  |  5    |    test5    |     John Doe   |     0    |
  +-------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: you have an 'id' field

Comment: no, I what I mean is to merge the user so it only have 1 main account, it's normal to have an ID.

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Comment: then provide your answers, if you an idea. thank you

Comment: How can you know that the same name corresponds to the same person?

Comment: it's not like facebook that anyone see others name and set their name as the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose which id you think is main.
I selected MIN(id)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `username` VARCHAR(5),
>   `name` VARCHAR(10),
>   `main` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `username`, `name`, `main`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'test1', 'John Doe', '0'),
>   ('2', 'test2', 'John Doe', '0'),
>   ('3', 'test3', 'John Doe', '0'),
>   ('4', 'test4', 'John Doe', '0'),
>   ('5', 'test5', 'John Doe', '0'),
>     ('6', 'test1', 'John Dowe', '0'),
>   ('7', 'test2', 'John Dowe', '0'),
>   ('8', 'test3', 'John Dowe', '0'),
>   ('9', 'test4', 'John Dowe', '0'),
>   ('10', 'test5', 'John Dowe', '0');
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE table1 SET main = 1 WHERE id IN (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM (SELECT * FROM table1) s GROUP BY name)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | username | name      | main
> -: | :------- | :-------- | ---:
>  1 | test1    | John Doe  |    1
>  2 | test2    | John Doe  |    0
>  3 | test3    | John Doe  |    0
>  4 | test4    | John Doe  |    0
>  5 | test5    | John Doe  |    0
>  6 | test1    | John Dowe |    1
>  7 | test2    | John Dowe |    0
>  8 | test3    | John Dowe |    0
>  9 | test4    | John Dowe |    0
> 10 | test5    | John Dowe |    0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5cb25762e009b4222cdcb498d4e1d449)*

Comment: thank you nbk, this is exactly what I am trying to achieve